# Model's validation test does not work in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I wanted to see if the validation was working properly, so I wrote a test of the model in Rspec.

models/work_history.rb

```
class WorkHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  validates :name,
            :since_date,
            :position, presence: true
  validates :is_employed, inclusion: [true, false]
  validates :until_date, presence: true, if: -> { :is_employed == false }
end
```

factories/work_histories.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :work_history do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "#{n}_company" }
    since_date { '2017-04-01' }
    until_date { '2021-03-01' }
    is_employed { false }
    position { 'director' }
    department { 'sales' }

    association :account
  end
end
```

spec/models/work_history_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe WorkHistory, type: :model do
  let(:account) { create(:account) }
  let(:work_history) { build(:work_history, account: account) }

  it "is invalid when is_employed is false and until_date is nil" do
    work_history.is_employed = false
    work_history.until_date = ''
    expect(work_history.valid?).to eq(false)
  end

  it "is invalid when is_employed is employed" do
    work_history.is_employed = 'employed'
    expect(work_history.valid?).to eq(false)
  end
end
```

then I run rspec command, but the test did't pass.

this is the rspec test error log

```
docker-compose run app rspec spec/models
Creating toei-works_app_run ... done
FF

Failures:

  1) WorkHistory is invalid when is_employed is false and until_date is nil
     Failure/Error: expect(work_history.valid?).to eq(false)

       expected: false
            got: true

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -false
       +true

     # ./spec/models/work_history_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) WorkHistory is invalid when is_employed is employed
     Failure/Error: expect(work_history.valid?).to eq(false)

       expected: false
            got: true

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -false
       +true

     # ./spec/models/work_history_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know why Rspec tests fail

Why can't I  pass rspec's test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not structuring the if part of your validation correctly. You're currently checking whether the symbol `:is_employed?` equals false, which it never will. You can check out the correct syntax here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

You can either do

```
class WorkHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  validates :name,
            :since_date,
            :position, presence: true
  validates :is_employed, inclusion: [true, false]
  validates :until_date, presence: true, if: -> { :not_employed? }

  private

  def not_enployed?
    !is_employed?
  end
end
```

or

```
class WorkHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  validates :name,
            :since_date,
            :position, presence: true
  validates :is_employed, inclusion: [true, false]
  validates :until_date, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |work_history| work_history.is_employed? }
end
```

Comment: Thanks you answerting.
I implemented it as I was told and it worked correctly!!